# Unable to do Single LogOut (SLO) in CAS with 3 client applications. (Spring Security 4.2.1.RELEASE + SSO CAS - jasig 4.0.3)

Tags: session, cookies, spring-security, cas, jasig

I'm using CAS with three applications, when I try to logout from one of then, CAS kill the session from that application, but the session remains in the others applications. How do I kill all the sessions?

- CAS
- APPLICATION A
- APPLICATION B
- APPLICATION C

logouts from application A, remais logged in applications B and C.

I wasn't able to get all cookies, only from the application where the logout method is in.

Anyone can assist on this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fundamental here is to logout out the local application sessions and then call the cas logout service. I would imagine this is how your application logout controller would look like

```java
public ModelAndView logout(HttpServletRequest request) {
    SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
    request.getSession(false).invalidate();
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/logout/cas");
}
```

when you redirect to **/logout/cas** the following entries in spring-security.xml will take care of single logout.

```xml
<!-- This filter handles a Single Logout Request from the CAS Server -->
<bean id="singleLogoutFilter" class="org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutFilter">
    <property name="artifactParameterName" value="SAMLart"></property>
</bean>

<!-- This filter redirects to the CAS Server to signal Single Logout should be performed -->
<bean id="requestSingleLogoutFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter">
    <constructor-arg value="https://${cas.server.name}/cas/logout" />
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SecurityContextLogoutHandler" />
    </constructor-arg>
    <property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/logout/cas" />
</bean>
```

Following link should be helpful, [CAS Single Logout](https://apereo.github.io/cas/4.2.x/installation/Logout-Single-Signout.html). Please note that this link is for CAS version 4.2.x.

Comment: Thank you at the time helped me a lot.